# OpenGL render only a part of VBOs

Tags: opengl, vbo

I have a VBO with a IBO and I want to render for example the second triangle and in the next render step I want to render the third triangle.

I think the correct way to render the second triangle ist to call

```
glDrawArrays(GL_TRIANGLES, 
             3,  // indexArray[3] is start
             3); // take 3 indices (from index 3..5 --> second triangle)
```

It works fine with the first triangle. But when I want to render another triangle the parameters of the VBO will be interpreted not correctly.

The definition of my VAO looks like this

```
glGenVertexArrays(1, out VAO);
glBindVertexArray(VAO);
glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, VBO.V_ID);
glBindBuffer(GL_ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, VBO.E_ID);

glEnableVertexAttribArray(0);
glVertexAttribPointer(0, 2, GL_FLOAT, false, 12 * sizeof(float), 0);
glBindAttribLocation(shaderID, 0, "InUV");
glEnableVertexAttribArray(1);
glVertexAttribPointer(1, 4, GL_FLOAT, true, 12 * sizeof(float), 2 * sizeof(float));
glBindAttribLocation(shaderID, 1, "InColor");
glEnableVertexAttribArray(2);
glVertexAttribPointer(2, 3, GL_FLOAT, true, 12 * sizeof(float), 6 * sizeof(float));
glBindAttribLocation(shaderID, 2, "InNormal");
glEnableVertexAttribArray(3);
glVertexAttribPointer(3, 3, GL_FLOAT, false, 12 * sizeof(float), 9 * sizeof(float));
glBindAttribLocation(shaderID, 3, "InVertex");

glBindVertexArray(0);
```

When I call

```
glDrawElements(GL_TRIANGLES, VBO.length, GL_UNSIGNED_INT, 0);
```

The object will render correctly.

Does I use glDrawArrays in a wrong way or is there another way to render one special triangle of a VBO???

Answer (score 4):

`glDrawElements` and `glDrawArrays` are different, `glDrawArrays` will ignore the index buffer

instead you should do:

```
usigned int *NULLptr=0;
glDrawElements(GL_TRIANGLES, 3, GL_UNSIGNED_INT, (void*)(NULLptr+3));
```

note the offset specified, you can also do this in place with `(void*)(3*sizeof(unsigned int))`